# Weird number of events in case of adding an element including serverTimestamp fields to a firestore collection

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm writing a web based application allowing users to exchange messages regarding a specific topic. I use firebase as a backend, the data is stored in Firestore. The stored message is a fairly simple object, it roughly contains an ID, the content and two server based timestamps as creation and lastupdate time. I listen to changes using the valueChange() method. Every time I add a new message object to firestore using the set() method, I receive two updates instead of the expected one. 
Is this normal behavior? Is the creation of the serverTimestamp considered as an update of the data, and that's the reason why I receive two events?

Below my code. The function getData() is triggered by clicking a button on the web page.

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-access',
  templateUrl: './access.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./access.component.scss']
})
export class AccessComponent implements OnInit {

  m: Message;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private _db: AngularFirestore, 
    private _auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('START...');
    this.subscription = this._db.collection<any>(MESSAGES_ENDPOINT).valueChanges()
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log('data received: ', response);
      });

  }

  getData(): void {
    this.m = {
      id: this._db.createId(),
      title: ' Just a test',
      message: 'MESSAGE ' + new Date().getSeconds(),
      type: 1,
      topic: '999999',
      state: 0,
      from: this._auth.getUserID(),
      fromAvatar: this._auth.getAvatar(),
      fromDisplayName: this._auth.getDisplayName(),
      to: 'JOE COOL',
      created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      lastUpdate: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    };

    this._db.collection<Message>(MESSAGES_ENDPOINT).doc(this.m.id).set(this.m)
    .then(() => console.log('Document successfully stored'))
    .catch((error) => console.error('Error writing document: ', error));
  }
}
```

As a result I receive the following output:

```
START...
access.component.ts:30 data received:  
(2) [{…}, {…}]  <== **after subscription, returns data already stored in database **


access.component.ts:30 data received:  <== ** after submission of new entry, surprisingly **the timestamp fields are null** 
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {created: Timestamp, from: "R1qkoc1LPefeNTO1fdSKnBJbHE92", fromAvatar: "/assets/images/avatars/avatar_placeholder.png", fromDisplayName: "Guest", id: "Da7Bpaw2Y4ZzSqa44eqb", …}
1: **{created: null**, from: "R1qkoc1LPefeNTO1fdSKnBJbHE92", fromAvatar: "/assets/images/avatars/avatar_placeholder.png", fromDisplayName: "Guest", id: "HeY4dqqhwVEUgNIpczCo", …}
2: {created: Timestamp, from: "R1qkoc1LPefeNTO1fdSKnBJbHE92", fromAvatar: "/assets/images/avatars/avatar_placeholder.png", fromDisplayName: "Guest", id: "RyDq5pwW0DvnErXH6J2M", …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)

access.component.ts:30 data received:  <== ** Second update, this time with correct timestamp fields
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {created: Timestamp, from: "R1qkoc1LPefeNTO1fdSKnBJbHE92", fromAvatar: "/assets/images/avatars/avatar_placeholder.png", fromDisplayName: "Guest", id: "Da7Bpaw2Y4ZzSqa44eqb", …}
1: {**created: Timestamp**, from: "R1qkoc1LPefeNTO1fdSKnBJbHE92", fromAvatar: "/assets/images/avatars/avatar_placeholder.png", fromDisplayName: "Guest", id: "HeY4dqqhwVEUgNIpczCo", …}
2: {created: Timestamp, from: "R1qkoc1LPefeNTO1fdSKnBJbHE92", fromAvatar: "/assets/images/avatars/avatar_placeholder.png", fromDisplayName: "Guest", id: "RyDq5pwW0DvnErXH6J2M", …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior.  The SDK guesses the value of the timestamp for the sake of any local listeners that will get triggered when any of its documents change for any reason.  Then, when the actual value is known from the server, the listener will be triggered again with the new value.

If you don't want the local updates and only those from the server, then you will have to indicate for the query that you are only interested in document snapshots the come directly from the server.  I don't know how AngularFire exposes this, but in the pure JavaScript version of the SDK, you look at the [hasPendingWrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata#~hasPendingWrites) attribute of SnapshotMetadata.  You can get snapshot metadata by indicating that you want to [receive metadata changes in the query][2].